# Optimizing Bayesian estimation as a function of a parameter

Tags: bayesian

**GENERAL QUESTION**

Imagine a system with a statistical variable $X$ and a parameter $\theta$ that we want to determine.
Following the standard Bayesian estimation, a sequence of $N$ measurements will be taken, getting the values $\{ x_1, \dots, x_N \}$.
Then, the conditional probability $ P( \theta | x_N,x_{N-1},\dots,x_1 ) $ can be determined as follows:
\begin{align}
    P( \theta | x_N,x_{N-1},\dots,x_1 ) =
    \frac{1}{\mathcal{N}}
    \prod_{i=1}^N P( x_i | \theta )
    P_0(\theta) \, .
    \qquad \qquad \mathrm{(1)}
\end{align}
Here, $ P_0(\theta) $ is a prior distribution of the parameter, $\mathcal{N}$ is a normalization constant and $ P( x_i | \theta ) $ is known.
So far, this is just the application of Bayes' theorem $N$ times.

But now, let $\tau$ encode an extra degree of freedom that appears in $ P( x | \theta ) \equiv P_{\tau}( x | \theta )$.
$\tau$ is not a property of the system under study, but just a variable whose value $\tau_i$ we can choose at each measurement $i$.
In that case, Eq. (1) turns into:
\begin{align}
    P( \theta | x_N,x_{N-1},\dots,x_1 ) =
    \frac{1}{\mathcal{N}}
    \prod_{i=1}^N P_{\tau_i} ( x_i | \theta )
    P_0(\theta) \, .
    \qquad \qquad \mathrm{(2)}
\end{align}

**Question:** How can Bayesian inference, Eq. (2), be optimized as a function of $\tau$?
In other words, is there an optimal choice of $ \{ \tau_1, \dots, \tau_N \}$ for the estimation of $\theta$?

**EXAMPLE**

This example is a very unrealistic coin-flip experiment, but it can serve to illustrate the question.
Let the following rules apply:

1. A coin is tossed $N$ times.
2. **The coin is always tossed with the same angular velocity $\theta$** and from the same position (e.g., heads).
   The angle $\phi$ as a function of time $t$ is given by $ \phi(t) = \theta t $, see the outline:
   [image]
3. The coin turns for a time $\tau$ before it hits the ground.
   We can choose this time $\tau_i$ at each toss $i$ by tossing the coin from the appropriate height.
4. When the coin hits the ground, the probability that it is heads ($x = 1$) or tails ($x = -1$) is given by the following function:
   \begin{align}
       P_{\tau}(x|\theta) =
       \frac{1}{2}
       \left[ 1 + x \cos( \theta \tau ) \right] \, .
   \end{align}
   For example, if the coin hits the ground at an angle $\phi(\tau) = \theta \tau = 2 m \pi$, $m \in \mathcal{Z}$ (namely in the heads position), the result will be heads.
   $\phi(\tau) = (2m+1)\pi$, $m \in \mathcal{Z}$ (getting to the floor as tails) will always yield tails, whereas $\phi(\tau) = (2m+1)\pi/2$, $m\in\mathcal{Z}$ (that is, the coin hitting the ground with the edge) yields a $50\%$ chance of getting heads or tails.
5. Assume the prior distribution $P_0(\theta)$ to be a Gaussian.

In this context, the question is: how should I choose the times $\{\tau_1,\dots,\tau_N\}$ (equivalently, the heights from which the coin is tossed) so that I can estimate the angular frequency $\theta$ better?